# How to find real and imaginary parts of this complex exponential sum?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates, exponential-sum

I understand how to find real and imaginary parts of regular complex exponentials using Euler's formulas, but this one stumps me:

$$6e^{-0.3t+0.8 \pi t j}$$

By using rules of exponents, I can do the following:

$$6e^{-0.3t}e^{0.8\pi t j}$$

And from here I'm stuck because the "$t$" in both exponents screws me up. Any insight is greatly appreciated, thank you!

(I'm sorry for the ugly equation formatting, Stack Exchange doesn't allow me to post equation pics until I have a certain reputation)

Comment: Treat $t$ as if it is any real number.

Comment: Notice that $e^{ix} = cos(x) + isin(x)$ if x (in your case t) is real you can split it up in this way.